# Type of returned data from Firebase using Pyrebase

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pyrebase

When receiving data from Pyrebase, I expect it to be a dictionary, containing keys and values. But sometimes, after parsing the data, I don't get a dictionary. It's a list of value and I don't get to know the keys. Am I doing anything wrong?

Here is an example where "parsed" is a dict:

```
raw_data = db.child("UploadedImages").order_by_child("Timestamp") \
    .start_at(self.start_from).limit_to_first(3).get()
parsed = json.loads(json.dumps(raw_data .val()))
```

and here the returned data is a list:

```
users_raw = db.child("UploadedImages").order_by_child("Timestamp").get()
parsed = json.loads(json.dumps(users_raw.val()))
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the JSON data (as text, no screenshots please) that is being returned as a type that you don't expect? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put indexes as keys on firebase, you won't get the keys. However, if even one of those keys is any random string, you'll get the keys too. I don't really know why, but that was the solution for me.

So instead of using 1, 2, 3... use a random string or firebase's default key generator.

You can check this by exporting data from your firebase dashboard (thanks to [Frank van Puffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen)'s comment which gave me the idea of checking it)